# Getting wrong data back when reading from binary file

Tags: c++, io, istream

I'm having an issue reading in some bytes from a yuv file (it's 1280x720 if that matters) and was hoping someone could point out what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting different results using the read command and using an istream iterator . Here's some example code of what I'm trying to do:

```
void readBlock(std::ifstream& yuvFile, YUVBlock& destBlock, YUVConfig& config, const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y, const bool useAligned = false)
{
    //Calculate luma offset
    unsigned int YOffset = (useAligned ? config.m_alignedYFileOffset : config.m_YFileOffset) +
    (destBlock.yY * (useAligned ? config.m_alignedYUVWidth : config.m_YUVWidth) + destBlock.yX);// *config.m_bitDepth;

//Copy Luma data
//yuvFile.seekg(YOffset, std::istream::beg);
    for (unsigned int lumaY = 0; lumaY < destBlock.m_YHeight && ((lumaY + destBlock.yY) < config.m_YUVHeight); ++lumaY)
    {
        yuvFile.seekg(YOffset + ((useAligned ? config.m_alignedYUVWidth : config.m_YUVWidth)/* * config.m_bitDepth*/) * (lumaY), std::istream::beg);
        int copySize = destBlock.m_YWidth;
        if (destBlock.yX + copySize > config.m_YUVWidth)
        {
            copySize = config.m_YUVWidth - destBlock.yX;
        }
        if (destBlock.yX >= 1088 && destBlock.yY >= 704)
        {
            char* test = new char[9];
            yuvFile.read(test, 9);

            delete[] test;
            yuvFile.seekg(YOffset + ((useAligned ? config.m_alignedYUVWidth : config.m_YUVWidth)/* * config.m_bitDepth*/) * (lumaY));
        }

        std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> start = std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(yuvFile);
        std::copy_n(start, copySize, std::back_inserter(destBlock.m_yData));

    }
}
struct YUVBlock
{
std::vector<uint8_t> m_yData;
std::vector<uint8_t> m_uData;
std::vector<uint8_t> m_vData;
unsigned int m_YWidth;
unsigned int m_YHeight;
unsigned int m_UWidth;
unsigned int m_UHeight;
unsigned int m_VWidth;
unsigned int m_VHeight;

unsigned int yX;
unsigned int yY;
unsigned int uX;
unsigned int uY;
unsigned int vX;
unsigned int vY;
};
```

This error only seems to be happening at X =1088 and Y = 704 in the image. I'm expecting to see a byte value of 10 as the first byte I read back. When I use

```
yuvFile.read(test, 9);
```

I get 10 as my first byte. When I use the istream iterator:

```
std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> start = std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(yuvFile);
    std::copy_n(start, copySize, std::back_inserter(destBlock.m_yData));
```

The first byte I read is 17. 17 is the byte after 10 so it seems the istream iterator skips the first byte.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1. Make sure your file is opened in `std::ios::binary` mode. 2. Use `std::istreambuf_iterator`. I suspect your `10` is being skipped as a text-mode linefeed ([see this chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)).

Comment: Ah yea, you're probably right. I can;t get my istreambuf_iterator to take in my istream though. I should be able to do this shouldn't I?

    `std::copy_n((std::istreambuf_iterator<uint8_t>(yuvFile)), copySize, std::back_inserter(destBlock.m_yData));`

Answer (score 2):

There is a major difference between `istream::read` and `std::istream_iterator`.

`std::istream::read` performs unformatted read.
`std::istream_iterator` performs formatted read.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator

> `std::istream_iterator` is a single-pass input iterator that reads successive objects of type `T` from the `std::basic_istream` object for which it was constructed, by calling the appropriate `operator>>`.

If your file was created using `std::ostream::write` or `fwrite`, you must use `std::istream::read` or `fread` to read the data.

If your file was created using any of the methods that create formatted output, such as `std::ostream::operato<<()`, `fprintf`, you have a chance to read the data using `std::istream_iterator`.